# Releasing memory of specific UIVIewController in the navigationController stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

Basically I have an app that has introductory views. Once you reach a certain view, the previous views are no longer accessible at all, so I want to remove them from the stack and free any memory they have consumed. What is the best way to do this? Right now I am doing something like

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
NSArray *allControllersCopy2 = [allViewControllers copy];
for (id object in allControllersCopy2) {
    if([allControllersCopy2 indexOfObject:object] == ([allControllersCopy2 count] - 1)){
        NSLog(@"IGNORE CURRENT VIEW");
    }
    else{
        [allViewControllers removeObject:object];
        [object release];
    }

}
self.navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
[allControllersCopy2 release];
```

Does this actually release the memory consumed by these views? or does it simply remove the view from the stack array?

Answer (score 2):

When you are ready to push "that certain view", use setViewControllers:animated: to replace the stack with your final ViewController, instead of using pushViewController to add it to the stack.

assuming controller = 'that certain view'...

don't do [self.navigation pushViewController:controller animated:YES], do:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:controller] animated:YES];
```

this will release all the previous View Controllers, their dealloc methods will get called, memory release, etc